# Why could Supergirl not breathe in space?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

In the [Supergirl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl_(TV_series)) episode "[Better Angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Angels_(Supergirl))" we have the following exchange between Kara (Supergirl) and her sister:

> **Alex:** *Once you're in space, there's no atmosphere. There's no gravity. You wouldn't be able to generate thrust, you wouldn't be able to breathe,
>   you wouldn't be able to get back.*
>
> **Kara:** *There is no other way.*

---

My question is, **why was Supergirl unable to breathe in space?**

Comment: http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/0/2532/601354-superman204_16_17.jpg

Comment: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4-tw1r9Y02E/Vu-FWuI-OrI/AAAAAAAAAhw/44q4Fg6c330B9SJRCEjKDnGVEcMxNfz9QCL0B/w311-h553-no/supergirl%2Bcan%2527t%2Bbreathe%2Bin%2Bspace%2B-%2B1

Comment: Because she's [not Batman](http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/BatSpace.gif).

Comment: Some Supergirls can't breath in space, some can... Pretty simple really

Comment: What would she breathe?

Answer (score 21):

> why could Supergirl not be able to breathe in space?

Because no-one can...there's no air.

She can't breathe in space unless she stores solar energy and **holds her breath.**

In the modern version of Superman (in the comics at least until the next version), Superman's sight, stamina and breath powers have been substantially reduced, and the **character was also shown as requiring an oxygen mask for prolonged travel in space or underwater.**

The same would apply to Supergirl.

I suspect though you are asking why Supergirl became unconscious and had to be rescued.

Well, she'd just lifted the 1 million ton Fort Rozz into orbit and beyond...that would have expended a...*ahem*...superhuman amount of energy which would have depleted her reserves. Plus the air is essentially too thin to breathe over 10,000 meters and Earth orbit is **substantially** higher than that.

So, she ran out of energy and breath and fell unconscious.

Comment: **Prison Warden:** *There ain't no air in space!* **Homer:** *There's an air and space museum.*

Comment: @Valorum That's where they keep the famous air and the historic space.

Comment: The thrust bit is a bit tricky, but the breathing but is quite reasonable. In the early days, Superman's abilities were quite limited. He then gained loads of wacky powers in the 1960s and 70s (time travel, flying through space, etc etc) which were dialed back in the 80s and 90s. By now he's gone from not being able to breathe in space to being able to breathe in space and back again a couple of times depending on which film/comic/TV show you're watching.

Comment: @Paulie_D - But the writers know much more than the characters do. Characters can say the wrong things, even if the writers know better.

Comment: @Valorum Oh, you mean like memory-wiping kisses... *sigh*

Comment: @Paulie_D - Lois Lane can say "Clark Kent can't be Superman" even though the writer knows damn well he is.

Comment: Right so you mean Alex doesn't know  that Kara can fly in space? I think I may remove that part..its not relevant to the question and causing debate.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I think the problem here is that the OP is expecting consistent canon abilities from a character who's gone through at least 50+ iterations, each with their own unique powers and limitations.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got your info, but this assertion is laughable: *the air is essentially too thin to breathe over 10,000 feet*. Having vigorously exercised over 15,000 feet, I can assure you that you are incorrect.

Comment: Maybe they meant 10,000 metres.

Comment: It's orbital heights, so it's probably not 10,000 feet.  Airplanes fly higher than that all the time, and they're not close to being in orbit.

Comment: Being in orbit is about how fast you are going sideways, not about how high you are.  Obligatory xkcd link: [Orbital speed](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/).

Comment: @Makyen but you can't *stay* in orbit that low in atmo. you would be flying, not orbiting

Comment: [the highest city in the world is at 5100m (that's 16700ft for you)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest_cities_in_the_world), and 50000 people live there

Comment: Yeah that must have been a typo, I have been in Cerro de Pasco (14,370 feet according to @njxk2's wiki link, and while altitude sickness is common, it's still livable.

Answer (score -2):

Well since superman has done things like held a miniature blackhole in the palm of his hand or picked up all of earth's nuclear missiles and threw them in the sun or when he pulled whole planets around for supergirl to be so weak only thing I can think of is that she was on earth for a shorter amount of time with the added fact there's plenty of proof stating that female kryptonions are a bit weaker but still she should have been able to atleast fly back

Comment: Those things happened in a different continuity.